# Best way to handle errors caused by trying to order rows in a DataGridView with null values

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

If you add some `null` values on some cells in a `DataGridView` and then try to order by the column where the `null` values were added by clicking on the header, you will get a *"Object must be of type String"* exception, and the program will crash. How should I handle this? I want the user to be able to order by clicking on the header. Does this mean my only choice is to replace all `null` or `DBNull` values to something like `""`? Or can I somehow catch the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is the data on the grid? If it is data-bound to a collection, you can implement `IBindingList` and provide your own `ApplySort` method that accounts for `null` however you choose. You also need to provide suitable implementations of `SupportsSorting`, `SortDirection` and `SortProperty`.

But *personally*, I would just remove the `null`s for now; so yes, a `""` is a reasonable alternative to `null` in a string column; trickier for some other cases.

Comment: Is not data bound to anything. I'm still not sure about the replacing null for "". It's kinda messy since I don't only use strings. Is there any other option for non-data-bound `DataGridView`'s?